# Finding closest anchor href via scrollOffset

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, anchor

I have a `UIWebView` with an HTML page completely loaded. The `UIWebView` has a frame of 320 x 480 and scrolls horizontally. I can get the current offset a user is currently at. I would like to find the closest anchor using the XY offset so I can "jump to" that anchors position. Is this at all possible? Can someone point me to a resource in Javascript for doing this?

```
<a id="p-1">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text<a id="p-2">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text ...
```

**Update**

My super sad JS code:

```
function posForElement(e)
{
    var totalOffsetY = 0;

    do
    {
        totalOffsetY += e.offsetTop;
    } while(e = e.offsetParent)

    return totalOffsetY;
}

function getClosestAnchor(locationX, locationY)
{
    var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

    var currentAnchor;
    for (var idx = 0; idx < a.length; ++idx)
    {
        if(a[idx].getAttribute('id') && a[idx+1])
        {
            if(posForElement(a[idx]) <= locationX && locationX <= posForElement(a[idx+1])) 
            {
                currentAnchor = a[idx];
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                currentAnchor = a[0];
            }
        }
    }

    return currentAnchor.getAttribute('id');
}
```

Objective-C

```
float pageOffset = 320.0f;

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"GetAnchorPos" ofType:@"js"];
NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCode];

NSString *execute = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"getClosestAnchor('%f', '0')", pageOffset];
NSString *anchorID = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:execute];
```

Comment: Do you absolutely want via scrollOffset?

Comment: Do you want the closest anchor from the top left of the anchor or from the center or something else?

Comment: Given a current XY offset, I want the closest anchor from the top/left of the document.

Comment: Danny Boy, you didn’t comment much, have you tried our suggestions ?
There’s something wrong with this question… I feel a bit shocked that you didn’t even find useful the answer that is the most voted.

Comment: I have not been able to get any to work within an iOS application. I have have tried and modified each solution below countless times. I am trying now so that I can award to the bounty to the closest solution.

Comment: Does this work : http://denishovart.com/test.html ?

Comment: @Denis See additional comments on your answers' comment thread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** I rewrote the code to match all the anchors that have an id, and simplified the comparison of the norm of the vectors in my `sortByDistance` function.

Check my attempt [on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bdk6/8/embedded/result/) (the previous one was [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Denzen/3bdk6/3/embedded/result/) ).

The javascript part :

```
// findPos : courtesy of @ppk - see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
var findPos = function(obj) {
    var curleft = 0,
        curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        curleft = obj.offsetLeft;
        curtop = obj.offsetTop;
        while ((obj = obj.offsetParent)) {
            curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        }
    }
    return [curleft, curtop];
};

var findClosestAnchor = function (anchors) {

    var sortByDistance = function(element1, element2) {

        var pos1 = findPos( element1 ),
            pos2 = findPos( element2 );

        // vect1 & vect2 represent 2d vectors going from the top left extremity of each element to the point positionned at the scrolled offset of the window
        var vect1 = [
                window.scrollX - pos1[0],
                window.scrollY - pos1[1]
            ],
            vect2 = [
                window.scrollX - pos2[0],
                window.scrollY - pos2[1]
            ];

        // we compare the length of the vectors using only the sum of their components squared
        // no need to find the magnitude of each (this was inspired by Mageek’s answer)
        var sqDist1 = vect1[0] * vect1[0] + vect1[1] * vect1[1],
            sqDist2 = vect2[0] * vect2[0] + vect2[1] * vect2[1];

        if ( sqDist1 <  sqDist2 ) return -1;
        else if ( sqDist1 >  sqDist2 ) return 1;
        else return 0;
    };

    // Convert the nodelist to an array, then returns the first item of the elements sorted by distance
    return Array.prototype.slice.call( anchors ).sort( sortByDistance )[0];
};
```

You can retrieve and cache the anchors like so when the dom is ready :  `var anchors = document.body.querySelectorAll('a[id]');`

I’ve not tested it on a smartphone yet but I don’t see any reasons why it wouldn’t work.
[Here](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/function-declarations.html#L16) is why I used the `var foo = function() {};` form ([more javascript patterns](http://shichuan.github.com/javascript-patterns/)).

The `return Array.prototype.slice.call( anchors ).sort( sortByDistance )[0];` line is actually a bit tricky.

`document.body.querySelectorAll('a['id']')` returns me a NodeList with all the anchors that have the attribute "id" in the body of the current page.
Sadly, a NodeList object does not have a "sort" method, and it is not possible to use the `sort` method of the Array prototype, [as it is with some other methods, such as filter or map](http://javascriptisawesome.blogspot.fr/2012/05/sharing-prototypes-in-js.html) (`NodeList.prototype.sort = Array.prototype.sort` would have been really nice).

[This article](http://shifteleven.com/articles/2007/06/28/array-like-objects-in-javascript) explains better that I could why I used `Array.prototype.slice.call` to turn my NodeList into an array.

And finally, I used the `Array.prototype.sort` method (along with a custom `sortByDistance` function) to compare each element of the NodeList with each other, and I only return the first item, which is the closest one.

To find the position of the elements that use fixed positionning, it is possible to use this updated version of `findPos` : http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=331.

My answer may not be the more efficient (drdigit’s must be more than mine) but I preferred simplicity over efficiency, and I think it’s the easiest one to maintain.

**[YET ANOTHER UPDATE]**

Here is a heavily modified version of findPos that works with webkit css columns (with no gaps):

```
// Also adapted from PPK - this guy is everywhere ! - check http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html
var getStyle = function(el,styleProp)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}

// findPos : original by @ppk - see http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
// made recursive and transformed to returns the corect position when css columns are used

var findPos = function( obj, childCoords ) {
   if ( typeof childCoords == 'undefined'  ) {
       childCoords = [0, 0];
   }

   var parentColumnWidth,
       parentHeight;

   var curleft, curtop;

   if( obj.offsetParent && ( parentColumnWidth = parseInt( getStyle( obj.offsetParent, '-webkit-column-width' ) ) ) ) {
       parentHeight = parseInt( getStyle( obj.offsetParent, 'height' ) );
       curtop = obj.offsetTop;
       column = Math.ceil( curtop / parentHeight );
       curleft = ( ( column - 1 ) * parentColumnWidth ) + ( obj.offsetLeft % parentColumnWidth );
       curtop %= parentHeight;
   }
   else {
       curleft = obj.offsetLeft;
       curtop = obj.offsetTop;
   }

   curleft += childCoords[0];
   curtop += childCoords[1];

   if( obj.offsetParent ) {
       var coords = findPos( obj.offsetParent, [curleft, curtop] );
       curleft = coords[0];
       curtop = coords[1];
   }
   return [curleft, curtop];
}
```

Comment: No need to get all accusative. If you think something is amiss, flag for moderator attention and talk to *us* instead of starting arguments out here.

Comment: The JSFiddle does not work when the window is scaled down to 480 x 320 and you are scrolled over. It reports the incorrect number.

Comment: @Denis This works in the demo you provided (link in comment under question). But on my UIWebView, with a document of 2000 (width) and 480 height, it returns the same anchor each time. It may be worth noting, using other implementations and logging out each anchors scrollTop returns a number larger than the document. Logging out the document heigh returns the correct height.

Comment: @Denis try making this fixed height and with -webkit-column-width:320px and -webkit-column-gap:0 and it does not work. It only works when the document flows vertically.

Comment: Thanks anyway. This is the closest to what I was looking for.

Comment: @Denis I did not realize that made a difference.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to make it, without using scrollOffset. It's a bit complicated so if you have any question to understand it just comment.

HTML :

```
<body>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a />Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<a />Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
</body>
```

CSS :

```
body
{
    height:3000px;
}
```

JS :

```
var tempY;

function getClosestAnchor(e)
{
    if((window.event?event.keyCode:e.which)!=97)return;
    var allAnchors=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var allDiff=[];
    for(var a=0;a<allAnchors.length;a++)allDiff[a]=margeY(allAnchors[a])-tempY;
    var smallest=allDiff[0];
    for(var a=1;a<allDiff.length;a++)
    {
        if(Math.abs(smallest)>Math.abs(allDiff[a]))
        {
            smallest=allDiff[a];
        }
    }
    window.scrollBy(0,smallest);
}

function margeY(obj)
{
    var posY=0;
    if(!obj.offsetParent)return;
    do posY+=obj.offsetTop;
    while(obj=obj.offsetParent);
    return posY;
}

function update(e)
{
    if(e.pageY)tempY=e.pageY;
    else tempY=e.clientY+(document.documentElement.scrollTop||document.body.scrollTop)-document.documentElement.clientTop;
}


window.onkeypress=getClosestAnchor;
window.onmousemove=update;
```

Here is a fiddle demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/jswuC/

**Bonus :** You don't have to specify an id to all the anchors.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I seem to get an empty array for allAnchors and am trying to figure out if this is a problem because of the UIWebView component. The code is clear enough, I have an idea of what it does. I will try to adapt and post back here.

Comment: The array `allAnchors` is empty ??? Very strange ! You can post all your code if you want me to try to know why. PS : You understood that to scroll to the closest anchor you must press the `A` key ?

Comment: allAnchors is no longer NULL, but the jump still does not work.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy, check out a revised [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jswuC/1/) with only content changed. Before you begin, in Chrome for example, you  must click empty white HTML example area to draw focus/activate section. Then hover between examples and press letter A to scroll to nearest anchor.

Comment: @Mageek, +1 for clever use of distance algorithm explaining the heart of the code. Also, I did not know using Square Root is power performance issue and will keep that in mind.

Comment: @OhDannyBoy, I forgot to mention the starting point should be the Text Example you **can not see**, i.e., scroll to somewhere else so functionality of scroll to nearest anchor is realized.

Comment: i didn't really understand, but what must I change in this jsfiddle or the other so that my answer is accepted?

Comment: Pro Tip: Don't use `==` when you mean `===`, also cache the length of your for loops... `for(var i = 0; i < list.length` rechecks the length of the list each iteration. `for( var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l` is better (unless of course you are manipulating the list/array in the  loop and need this recheck)

Comment: Also, excluding `{` in functional block, whiles, ifs, etc.. makes your code very hard to read. micro optimizations (if this is what they are) should be handled by a compiler / compressor like YUI or Closure Compiler. just a tip.

Comment: Last Tip: Tacking this to the keypress on the document makes it so every time I hit 'a' I goto the closest anchor... ok cool... but what if i'm typing in a form? I realize this is likely for the example; just pointing it out incase the OP likes the idea and implements it

Comment: Look my other answer! It's really better.

Comment: @Mageek how would you return the ID? Following returns NULL.    var tempY;

function getClosestAnchor()
{

    var allAnchors=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var allDiff=[];
    for(var a=0;a<allAnchors.length;a++)allDiff[a]=margeY(allAnchors[a])-tempY;
    var smallest=allDiff[0];
    for(var a=1;a<allDiff.length;a++)
    {
        if(Math.abs(smallest)>Math.abs(allDiff[a]))
        {
            smallest=allDiff[a];
        }
    }
   return smallest.getAttribute('id');
}

Comment: This answer doesn't return the id(i wrote it before the bounty and before the added details). See my other answer and the fiddle and you will see that it's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Phew! I finished!

JS :

```
var x=0,y=0;//Here are the given X and Y, you can change them
var idClosest;//Id of the nearest anchor
var smallestIndex;
var couplesXY=[];
var allAnchors;
var html=document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
html.style.width="3000px";//You can change 3000, it's to make the possibility of horizontal scroll
html.style.height="3000px";//Here too

function random(min,max)
{
    var nb=min+(max+1-min)*Math.random();
    return Math.floor(nb);
}
function left(obj)//A remixed function of this site http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html
{
    if(obj.style.position=="absolute")return parseInt(obj.style.left);
    var posX=0;
    if(!obj.offsetParent)return;
    do posX+=obj.offsetLeft;
    while(obj=obj.offsetParent);
    return posX;
}
function top(obj)
{
    if(obj.style.position=="absolute")return parseInt(obj.style.top);
    var posY=0;
    if(!obj.offsetParent)return;
    do posY+=obj.offsetTop;
    while(obj=obj.offsetParent);
    return posY;
}

function generateRandomAnchors()//Just for the exemple, you can delete the function if you have already anchors
{
    for(var a=0;a<50;a++)//You can change 50
    {
        var anchor=document.createElement("a");
        anchor.style.position="absolute";
        anchor.style.width=random(0,100)+"px";//You can change 100
        anchor.style.height=random(0,100)+"px";//You can change 100
        anchor.style.left=random(0,3000-parseInt(anchor.style.width))+"px";//If you changed 3000 from
        anchor.style.top=random(0,3000-parseInt(anchor.style.height))+"px";//the top, change it here
        anchor.style.backgroundColor="black";
        anchor.id="Anchor"+a;
        document.body.appendChild(anchor);
    }
}
function getAllAnchors()
{
    allAnchors=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var a=0;a<allAnchors.length;a++)
    {
        couplesXY[a]=[];
        couplesXY[a][0]=left(allAnchors[a]);
        couplesXY[a][1]=top(allAnchors[a]);
    }
}
function findClosestAnchor()
{
    var distances=[];
    for(var a=0;a<couplesXY.length;a++)distances.push(Math.pow((x-couplesXY[a][0]),2)+Math.pow((y-couplesXY[a][1]),2));//Math formula to get the distance from A to B (http://euler.ac-versailles.fr/baseeuler/lexique/notion.jsp?id=122). I removed the square root not to slow down the calculations
    var smallest=distances[0];
    smallestIndex=0;
    for(var a=1;a<distances.length;a++)if(smallest>distances[a])
    {
        smallest=distances[a];
        smallestIndex=a;
    }
    idClosest=allAnchors[smallestIndex].id;
    alert(idClosest);
}
function jumpToIt()
{
    window.scrollTo(couplesXY[smallestIndex][0],couplesXY[smallestIndex][1]);
    allAnchors[smallestIndex].style.backgroundColor="red";//Color it to see it
}

generateRandomAnchors();
getAllAnchors();
findClosestAnchor();
jumpToIt();
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/W8LBs/2

PS : If you open this fiddle on a smartphone, it doesn't work (I don't know why) but if you copy this code in a sample on a smartphone, it works (but you must specify the `<html>` and the `<body>` section).

Comment: I do not have access to smartphone, but **jsFiddle** can be set to different HTML Doctype by accessing **INFO** on *Left Pane*. Default setting is **HTML5**. Also, maybe if you change empty body section to contain simple html and body tags it will then work on smartphone.

Comment: After looking a bit closer at your code, it looks like you tried to adapt for your own use the `findPos` function from Peter-Paul Koch that I also used, but you did it in a bad way.
In your `left` and `top` functions, where does this undefined `obj` variable come from ?

Comment: Thank you! I corrected it! I have adapted it so it gives the position even if the position is set to absolute.

Comment: If you take something from someone, it’s generally a good thing to say where it comes from in the first place. That’s why I donwvoted your answer, added to the fact that your code need serious refactoring.

Comment: This only returns the first element.

Comment: @Mageek First element relative to the current scroll offset in the document. This returns the very first anchor in the entire document regardless of position. As in anchors[0]

Comment: No! I generate random position of anchor. then i find the closest from point 0,0. and of course it will always be an anchor at the top. and if you open my fiddle you will see that it doesn't alert anchor1. Can you please tell me what should I have changed to get the bounty?

Answer (score 0):

**This answer has not received enough attention.**

Complete sample, fast (binary search) with caching for positions.

Fixed height and width, id of the closest anchor and scrollto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta>
<title>Offset 2</title>
<style>
body { font-family:helvetica,arial; font-size:12px; }
</style>
<script>
var ui = reqX = reqY = null, etop = eleft = 0, ref, cache;
function createAnchors()
{
    if (!ui)
    {
        ui = document.getElementById('UIWebView');
        reqX = document.getElementById('reqX');
        reqY = document.getElementById('reqY');
        var h=[], i=0;
        while (i < 1000)
            h.push('<a>fake anchor ... ',i,'</a> <a href=#>text for anchor <b>',(i++),'</b></a> ');
        ui.innerHTML = '<div style="padding:10px;width:700px">' + h.join('') + '</div>';
        cache = [];
        ref = Array.prototype.slice.call(ui.getElementsByTagName('a'));
        i = ref.length;
        while (--i >= 0)
        if (ref[i].href.length == 0)
            ref.splice(i,1);
    }
}
function pos(i)
{
    if (!cache[i])
    {
        etop = eleft = 0;
        var e=ref[i];
        if (e.offsetParent)
        {
            do
            {
                etop += e.offsetTop;
                eleft += e.offsetLeft;
            } while ((e = e.offsetParent) && e != ui)
        }
        cache[i] = [etop, eleft];       
    }
    else
    {
        etop = cache[i][0];
        eleft = cache[i][1];
    }
}
function find()
{
    createAnchors();
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(reqX.value))
    {
        alert ('I need a number for X');
        return;
    }   
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(reqY.value))
    {
        alert ('I need a number for Y');
        return;
    }
    var
        x = reqX.value,
        y = reqY.value,
        low = 0,
        hi = ref.length + 1, 
        med,
        limit = (ui.scrollHeight > ui.offsetHeight) ? ui.scrollHeight - ui.offsetHeight : ui.offsetHeight - ui.scrollHeight;
    if (y > limit)
        y = limit;
    if (x > ui.scrollWidth)
        x = (ui.scrollWidth > ui.offsetWidth) ? ui.scrollWidth : ui.offsetWidth;
    while (low < hi)
    {
        med = (low + ((hi - low) >> 1));
        pos(med);
        if (etop == y)
        {
            low = med;
            break;
        }
        if (etop < y)
            low = med + 1;
        else
            hi = med - 1;
    }
    var ctop = etop;
    if (eleft != x)
    {
        if (eleft > x)
            while (low > 0)
            {
                pos(--low);
                if (etop < ctop || eleft < x)
                {
                    pos(++low);
                    break;
                }
            }
        else
        {
            hi = ref.length;
            while (low < hi)
            {
                pos(++low);
                if (etop > ctop || eleft > x)
                {
                    pos(--low);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ui.scrollTop = etop - ui.offsetTop;
    ui.scrollLeft = eleft - ui.offsetLeft;
    ref[low].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
    alert(
        'Requested position: ' + x + ', ' + y + 
        '\nScrollTo position: ' + ui.scrollLeft + ', '+ ui.scrollTop + 
        '\nClosest anchor id: ' + low
        );
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=UIWebView style="width:320px;height:480px;overflow:auto;border:solid 1px #000"></div>
<label for="req">X: <input id=reqX type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value=200></label>
<label for="req">Y: <input id=reqY type=text size=5 maxlength=5 value=300></label>
<input type=button value="Find closest anchor" onclick="find()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The binary search part is great, kudos. There’s no doubt it’s more efficient than my simple Array.sort. But there are a few things you’re not taking into account. First, you’re not looking for the real coordinates of the element. `element.offsetTop` returns the top of an element relative to its parent. You can’t avoid traversing up the DOM tree to add each element's parent’s offsetTop.
Also, an element that has an anchor is not necessarily a link. And you forgot that the original poster asked for the closest anchor given a XY offset, while you’re only checking the Y offset of each element.

Comment: Splice anchor array elements with no href attribute (if required) and  change "top=a[med].offsetTop" with a while loop for parents. Finally for the X part, keep the low Y position, make a second binary search by setting hi=low+1, low=0 and change y, top and height references to x, left and width, incorporating the kept Y position for early break.

Comment: So you’d suggest performing a binary search twice on the list of items ?
I think it gets more complicated than necessary. Remember that “ premature optimization is the root of all evil ”. Binary search is not a bad idea, though.
If performance was a key point here, I think I’d still use the technique I suggested, but instead of Array.prototype.sort I would create and use a NodeList.prototype.binarySearch method.
Elements still would be compared once, based on the smallest norm of the vector going from their top left extremity to the top left extremity of the window.

Comment: Also, `document.body.querySelectorAll('[id]')` (or `document.body.querySelectorAll('a[id]')` if it needs to be links) work just fine to find element with anchors.

Comment: I'll study your code later (have to go) - but realized I got confused a little bit.
I thought "anchors" meant element you can link to using "#myAnchor". I never used it to designate the `a` tag… In french you just say "a link".
Anyway,`document.body.querySelectorAll('a[id]')` is what the OP is looking for.